# Каррирование в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, замыкания

**Каррирование** - способ предварительного заполнения первых нескольких аргументов функции (а также возврата новой функции).

Т.е., я могу в коде предварительно заполнить несколько аргументов, а при вызове указать недостающие?

```
Function.prototype.curry = function () {
    // Запомнить функцию и предварительно заполнить ее аргументами переменные
    var fn = this,
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // Эта функция должна получить на вход сохраненные аргументы и новые
    return function() {
        var arg = 0;
        // Объединить заранее подготовленные аргументы сохраненные в замыкании с новыми аргументами 
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length && arg < arguments.length; i++) {
            if (args[i] === undefined) {
                args[i] = arguments[arg++];
            }
        }
        // вызвать каррирующую функцию со всеми аргументами
        return fn.apply(this, args);
    };
};
```

Т.е., если каррировать данную функцию:

```
function sum (a,b) 
    return a + b;
```

То можно вызвать ее следующим образом:

```
var addTwo = sum.carry(2);
addTwo(5); // Увеличение на 2
// Но на выходе NaN
```

Правильно ли я все понял с каррированием, и где может быть ошибка?

Comment: а что вы пытались проверить этим условием? `args[i] === undefined`? Ну и выбран весьма своеобразный способ объединения аргументов, ведь первый набор _уже_ известен, нужно только добавить в него новый, нет смысла бежать по нему вновь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот код рабочий.

```
Function.prototype.curry = function () {
    // Запомнить функцию и предварительно заполнить ее аргументами переменные
    var fn = this,
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // Эта функция должна получить на вход сохраненные аргументы и новые
    return function() {
        var arg = 0;
        // Объединить заранее подготовленные аргументы сохраненные в замыкании с новыми аргументами
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length || arg < arguments.length; i++) {
            if (args[i] === undefined) {
                args[i] = arguments[arg++];
            }
        }
        // вызвать каррирующую функцию со всеми аргументами
        return fn.apply(this, args);
    };
};
function sum (a,b) {
    return a + b;
}
var addTwo = sum.curry(2);
console.log(addTwo(5)); // Выводит 7
```

Ваши ошибки: надо в уcловии цикла, где объединяете массивы аргументов писать `||` а не `&&`, чтобы ориентироваться на самый длинный из массивов. Также вы допустили описку в `var addTwo = sum.carry(2);`  - функция называется `curry`.